# Customized week number with date

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I make the start of the week 1 from 5/1/2016 and the end of the week 52 at 4/30/2017. For example: 5/1/2016 - 5/7/2016 should be week 1. SQL Server has the week counting with respect to the fiscal year. Is this possible? I am using SQL Server 2016.

```
select order_date,
datepart(week from order_date)weekorder, product_code 
from my_table
where  order_date > '4/30/2016'
and order_date < '5/1/2017'

order_date  weekorder   product_code    
2017-03-01      9         16PSS  
2016-11-26      48         16PZS
2016-11-18      47        16PSST
2016-05-31      23        16PRS
```

Requested:

```
order_date    weekorder    product_code 
2017-03-01      47         16PSS     
2016-11-26      22         16PZS
2016-11-18      21         16PSST
2016-05-31      5          16PRS
```

Comment: Just normalise your dates by subtracting 4 months, then use datepart week.

Comment: So do you want a Week as a count every 7 days from 5/1 regardless of what day of the week 5/1 is or do you always want the Sunday/Mon/Sat etc. of that week to be the start and then count from then?  Exampel can their be 53 weeks in a year or only 52.  ISO vs non... etc. here is a good article on it http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/pearlknows/2011/12/20/q-how-many-weeks-in-the-year-a-it-depends/

Comment: @DaleBurrell this doesn't work because simply subtracting 4 months doesn't maintain the actual day of the week.  E.g. 5/1/2017 is considered 2nd day of week but 4 months earlier is 1st day of week.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can use date arithmetic:

```
select order_date,
       datediff(day, '2016-04-30', order_date) / 7 as weekorder,
       product_code 
from my_table
where order_date > '2016-04-30' and
      order_date < '2017-05-01';
```

Comment: yes but this does assume that 5/1 regardless of what day of week it is will always be the start of the week.  So in this method if 5/1 is a Tuesday then Tuesday will always be the start of the week for the year...

Comment: @Matt . . . That is how I interpret "How can I make the start of the week 1 from 5/1/2016".

Comment: Hey Gordon, that `7` should be `-7`. Appreciate the help.

Comment: Also, I have `0` showing up for `weekorder` for the days from 5/1 to 5/7. Do you have any ideas? And the `1` week kicks off from 5/8.

Comment: @JakeWagner . . . You can just add 1 or use a different date for the difference.

Comment: Thanks. Add 1 to what?

Comment: @JakeWagner . . . `(1 + datediff(day, '2016-04-30', order_date) / 7) as weekorder`.